VHDL: Keep multiple files open until end of simulation
In my testbench I write to several outputs files as the test proceeds. These files are later processed by a Python script to generate meaningful data. The testbench writes 100,000s of lines of data in total.
At present I pass a file name with data to write, to a procedure. The procedure opens the file and writes a line and then closes the file. The data in the line will be later read and dissected by Python script so the line could be rather a long line. The Python script is run after the testbench has finished.
Now I suspect that, since I am using SSD, I should not be open a file to write a few hundred characters and then close it again. This will certainly cause more fatigue on the SSD on the long run due to how data storage works with SSD.
I also suspect that, opening and closing file to write each line is rather a slow process. If I open the file once, keep writing, and then flush and close at the very end, that will be a lot better.
I am using VUnit to write VHDL testbench. This means that there is one process that contains procedure for each test. This procedure calls other functions and procedures to execute communication with DUT and verification components and read/write files. There are not separate processes in the testbench at the present time but can be created. The way the testbench works, only one file is open at a time.
If what I suspected about file I/O and SSD is correct, how should I structure the testbench so that the relevant files are all opened once and then when all data is written, closed all at once. Maybe I can create a verification component that uses VUnit communication package and tell it to open and close files and once opened, I can send all data to write to file to this component. That is certainly a possiblity I believe.

How big files are we talking about? Is a ramdisk an option for you?

Might be a bit of a dumb question, but do you actually have a concrete problem with the way the files are written to, or is it just a suspicion that it might not be good for the SSD? Is it running too slowly in practice, or are you happy with the speed you have?

The files in total a few GB. The speed is slow, it takes several tens of minutes for the testbench to run fully. I believe that one reason is that I keep opening and closing the file for ever single line.

Please add clarifications to your question, comments are not for additional information. -- How many times do you plan to run the test bench in total on the same SSD?

I ran all the tests last night, each producing 1.6 million lines of results in dump file so I have the most data to process in the python scripts. There are 5 tests. I came back in the morning and they were not done. Total amounts to more than 30GB of data. I will have to repeat the test many times until I get satisfactory result from the algorithm that I am testing. Anyway, if I can't get any input here, I will figure out a way on my own.

Instead of opening the file in the procedure, create a file identifier in a package.  OSVVM does this in TranscriptPkg.vhd as shown below:
package TranscriptPkg is

  -- File Identifier to facilitate usage of one transcript file 
  file             TranscriptFile : text ;


Open the file using file_open.  I do this in the procedure TranscriptOpen:
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  procedure TranscriptOpen (Status: InOut FILE_OPEN_STATUS; ExternalName: STRING; OpenKind: WRITE_APPEND_OPEN_KIND := WRITE_MODE) is
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  begin
    file_open(Status, TranscriptFile, ExternalName, OpenKind) ;
    
    if Status = OPEN_OK then 
      CreateTranscriptYamlLog(ExternalName) ; 
      TranscriptEnable.Set(TRUE) ;
    end if ; 
  end procedure TranscriptOpen ; 

Then run have your procedures use TranscriptFile as the file identifier.  Procedures may be called with a file identifier.   The syntax is as follows.
procedure ProName (file FileID : text; ...  ) ;

At the end of the test, close the files with:
file_close(TranscriptFile) ;

This may or may not provide a performance gain.  File IO is buffered, so writes may be grouped together - although opening and closing it in VHDL may be expensive.   Since you expressed concern about performance, it would be interesting to know if this provided any performance gain.
I would do all of this in the test sequencer and not do it in a separate VC.

But this means that there is just 1 file open at a time since TranscriptFile can be just 1 file isn't it? So in my case I need to open a lot of files. I thought about creating an array of file type but that it seems is not permitted in VHDL. I am not sure why.

@quantum231 TranscriptFile is just one.   You can use the same approach to work with multiple file identifiers.    Arrays of file identifiers is supported in VHDL-2019 - if you are using Aldec, that probably works not - if not, then ask your vendor to implement it.

@quantum231   Also I would like to hear if there are performance differences by having the files open rather than opening and closing multiple times.

Jim, is there a way to pass pointer to a "file" variable into a procedure so that when the "writeline" is executed, it does so to a specific file that we have specified. This means less use of if/else blocks.

@quantum231  You can pass a file identifier to a procedure.

Lets say we have multiple "file TranscriptFileN : text ;" in the package, how can we pass this directly to a procedure so it uses it to write to it? I mean isn't file a pointer within VHDL? How is that supposed to be passed to a function?

@quantum231   procedure ProName (file FileID : text; ...  ) ;

@quantum231  Does my response at this point address your question?

yes, the question is marked as answered
